# Script to stop forever from crontab works only when manually called

Tags: cron, forever

Once a week I want to restart a forever script so I can compress the generated logfile and move it away.

For this I have created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# restarts the monitoring once per week to make sure the logifiles dont grow to big

today=`date -d "now" +"%Y%m%d-%H%M"`

echo 'Restarts the monitoring once per week to make sure the logfiles dont grow to big'
cd /home/app/monitoring
forever stop /home/app/monitoring/bin/monitoringd.js

echo 'rename old log'
echo 'mv /home/app/.forever/monitoring.log  /home/app/.forever/'$today'.log'
mv /home/app/.forever/monitoring.log  /home/app/.forever/$today.log
touch /home/app/.forever/monitoring.log

echo 'Start process with new log'

APP_ENV=production APP_PORT=7071 forever start -al /home/app/.forever/monitoring.log /home/app/monitoring/bin/monitoringd.js

echo 'Compress old log'
echo 'gzip /home/app/.forever/'$today'.log'
gzip /home/app/.forever/$today.log

cd /home/app/
```

When I run this manually it works as intended. When called from cronjob the forever process is not stopped and there fore the rest doesn't work either.

Any ideas why?
I already changed the paths to absolute paths and the crontab is the same like the user who runs the script manually.

Edit:
What I noticed is that a new log is created, but not used. It stays a 0 bytes and the output of the job goes presumably to /dev/null.

This is the crontab entry:

```
5   3  *  *  1 /home/app/cronjobs/utilities/newmonitoringlog.sh > /home/app/cronlog
```

Comment: Looks like a similar problem as this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278993/node-trying-to-restart-using-forever-wont-work-in-bash-script-on-cronjob
But that didn't get an answer either

Comment: Changed the script to use absolute paths for forever, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

but Add crontab PATH to "forever" location, worked fine.

```
PATH=/home/username/.nodebrew/current/bin
5   3  *  *  1 /home/app/cronjobs/utilities/newmonitoringlog.sh > /home/app/cronlog
```